# Accessing iOS user preference through UIA script for UI automation

Tags: ios, ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I've been trying to implement UI test script for my iOS application. In test cases I come over an issue of setting user's preference in setting. So far I could not find a way to change or read these user preference values.

These are what I have learn so far:

- setPreferencesValueForKey and preferencesValueForKey doesn't work by using identifier in Root.plist as a search key. It will return null. However, I can add these value via UIA script and the simulator seems to remember them but the application it self doesn't notice these changes.
- Tried set value for both ON and OFF in Setting.bundle, doesn't help.

My environment:

- I am using version 4.3.2 Xcode which instrument embedded in it.
- Mac OS X 10.7.3
- iPhone 5.1 simulator

Any thoughts?, thank you in advance for all advises, comments and solutions =)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977673

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach describe only works if running on iOS device
where it won't work on iOS simulator. So I just use the actual device to run the test script!
And that is my solution!